# Logical negation in front of variable c++

Tags: c++

I got this statement in a program.

I don't know what is the use of "!".

```
 while(ams && !ev);
```

Comment: Your title already says it, it is a logical negation. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!ev` is evaluated as `true` if `ev` converted to `bool` is `false`, otherwise `false`.

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.3.1 Unary operators

> 9
>   The operand of the logical negation operator ! is contextually converted to bool (Clause 4); its value is
>   true if the converted operand is false and false otherwise. The type of the result is bool.

Comment: i dont get it,let's assume that ev is 2 ,then 0.what happens?

Comment: 2 -> false, 0 -> true